# How to convert kilo to st and lbs using measurement framework

Tags: swift, measurement

I'm trying to convert my kilo values into stones and pounds i.e.

`78kg -> 12st 4lbs`

To make life easier i'm using the measurement framework to handle my conversions. Below is the following code i'm using to try and configure this conversion.

```
func convert(kilo: Double?) -> (stone: Double?, pounds: Double?) {
    guard let kilo = kilo else { return (stone: nil, pounds: nil) }
    let weightInKilos = Measurement(value: kilo, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)
    let stone = weightInKilos.converted(to: .stones).value.rounded(.towardZero)
    let difference = Measurement(value: stone, unit: UnitMass.stones).converted(to: .pounds)
    let pounds = (weightInKilos.converted(to: .pounds) - difference).value.rounded(.towardZero)
    return (stone: stone, pounds: pounds)
}
```

The problem i'm having is that i'm getting some strange values. When i try and convert 78kg into stone i'm getting a weird values on different devices. One one device the conversion is fine but on another i'm getting values like 488 stones, when it's trying to perform the conversion. I can't seem to put my finger on why this is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a note on API design: You shouldn't propagate optionals around like that. It's the caller's responsibility to handle their optionals, and call functions with unwrapped values when necessary. If this weren't the case, optional handling would be pervasive through *all* functions, at every layer of abstraction, and would be a complete mess. Plus, where will it stop? What if your caller has a double optional? Would you handle triple optionals for them too? What about triple?

Comment: 2) Even if you were to keep the optionalness here, it would be better to return `(stone: Double, pounds: Double)?` rather than `(stone: Double?, pounds: Double?)`, because you know that if you have `stone`, you have `pounds`, and vice versa. Their optionality is not independent, so don't model it as such

Comment: "One one device the conversion is fine but on another i'm getting values like 488 stones, when it's trying to perform the conversion." Could you provide more context on this? I couldn't replicate, this code is working fine for me.

Comment: By the way, your rounding of pounds towards 0 is making the result `12 st. 3 lbs.`, rather than the `12 st. 4 lbs.` you were looking for (the actual value is `12 st. 3.961 lb`). The `stone` component should be rounded towards zero, but I think you'll probably want the `pounds` component rounded towards the nearest integer

Comment: The most likely cause of this problem is that you're not actually passing 78 to the function on the other device. Double check with logging or breakpoints that you're passing what you think you're passing.